# Docker no encuentra archivo (y este existe)

Tags: django, docker, debian, pycharm

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Django, utilizo PyCharm en Windows 8.1. Para levantar el servidor web y la base de datos utilizo Docker instalado en Debian (Linux) a traves de una maquina virtual (no instale Docker de Windows por un problemas de compatibilidad).

Al ingresar a la maquina virtual, monto la carpeta de windows en dicha maquina:

```
mount.vboxsf csuperior /tmp/csuperior
```

Levanto el contenedor web y db desde la maquina virtual y cuando quiero insertar un punto de interrupción en el IDE, me sale el siguiente aviso:

> pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: /tmp/csuperior/reunion/views.py (will have no effect)

Lo raro es que el archivo en cuestión existe y la ruta es correcta. De hecho puedo modificarlo y los cambios surten efecto.

Para configurar el debug seguí el siguiente tutorial:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config
(sin la parte del SFTP, ya que los archivos los copio cuando monto la carpeta). En el "path mapping" utilizo las mismas carpetas que en el mount.vboxsf.

Gracias.

EDIT: Dejo el `docker-compose.yml` por las dudas

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: csuperior-postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: xxxx
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxxx
  broker:
    image: rabbitmq
    container_name: csuperior-broker
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=csuperior
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=csuBroker!!
  web:
    container_name: csuperior-web
    volumes:
      - .:/code/
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - broker
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuve un problema similar desarrollando con el stack Docker + Python 3.X + PyCharm. Tenía un problema de configuración del intérprete remoto de ython, que al parecer, tu tambien tienes mal configurado.

En primer lugar, me sorprende que no estés usando la integracion de pycharm con docker; si no que estas configurando el interprete remoto de manera manual.

Te invito a que te dirigas a el cuadro de diálogo `Configuración / Preferencias` `Ctrl + Alt + S`, seleccione `Proyecto <nombre del proyecto> | Intérprete de proyectos`. Haga clic en el icono Configurar el intérprete del proyecto y seleccione Agregar.

En el cuadro de diálogo que se abre, seleccione la opción Docker, en las listas desplegables, seleccione el servidor Docker (si falta el servidor, haga clic en Nuevo ...) y especifique el nombre de la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como resultado, en el cuadro de diálogo Configuración, debería ver algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto te debería funcionar. Para hacerlo correr correctamente me basé en este articulo: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html

Quedo atento a tus comentarios.